# Javascript - Make the whole div clicable

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have a parent div element, and within it a child div element. Now there is a click handler for the child div, it brings a drop down(like a menu).

Requirement - Is to bring the dropdown on click of the parent div also.

Note - on click of parent div, and firing childdiv.click() won't work, infinite loop.

Cannot do a stoppropagation, functionality for bringing the dropdown won't work.

Comment: Please share your code. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#child").click(function(){
      $("ul").slideUp();
  })
  
  $("#parent").click(function(){
      $("#child").trigger("click");
  })

})
```

```css
#parent {
  padding: 50px;
  background: red;
}
#child {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
li {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">Parent
  <div id="child">
    Child
    <ul id="menu" class="hide">
      <li>menu1</li>
      <li>menu2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The above code would not work! it goes in to a loop. parent clicked, which triggers child click and then the click bubbles up to parent and again child and the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this adding the parent onclick event handler and then use event.stopPropagation to stop event bubbling.

```
$("#child").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("ul").slideToggle();
});

$("#parent").click(function(e){
  $("#child").trigger("click");
});
```

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/zub7eju1/12/) is this what you want? Not sure what you want to do next. Adding your code would have been much easier to help.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine in jsfiddle, but the same code does not work in w3school editor. Can you let me know why? and your code works as required.

Comment: Your welcome @user3763367, I'm not sure about W3school editor. But have you tried it in your code? If it helped you can accept the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the stop propagation ceases the functionality from getting executed.the functionality is not as simply written as our sample code. An alternative solution without the stoppropagation would work i guess.

Comment: stoppropagation wont help, any other alternative?

Comment: Please add your code it would give us the direction. A fiddle would be better.